# Where to get started with querying TFS database/warehouse?

Tags: workitem, tfs-sdk, wiql

Right now all I have is a link to the tfs portal http://...

I'd like to either write an app that queries directly or
write a SQL query that queries the database (which I do not know the server address for or how to determine the database or warehouse server info)

If you are familiar with any tips, techniques or resources, please advise?!

End Goal:
1. Interrogate WOrkitems based on varying criteria for external reporting.

Comment: I might put together a detailed blog post on 5x1llz.com sometime but here is the best I could gather: 
1. Download ExiaProcess.TfsInterface
2. Import the project into yours
3. Reference the Microsoft.Teamfoundation.Client and Microsoft.Teamfoundation.WorkItemtracking.Client dll's
4. Connect to the server using the Uri, select a Tfsproject to work with 
5. Query to your hearts content...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an msdn site about TFS 2008 warehouse architecture and stuff.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244696%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

TFS 2010 warehouse is different in structure but the path to follow is similar for a beginner so the documentation should do good for you.